# Git submodules in existing gradle project

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, git-submodules

I have some application which has few modules that i want to to replace in submodule.
Can I do that in the current project. Create new repo with these modules.

Comment: Is this a gradle project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this in following way :

Say your main project is in X_REPO\Project\app

Move your module in a separate repo say Y_REPO

Then add Y REPO as submodule in X_REPO\Module1

Now make the following changes in

### settings.gradle

```
include ':Module1'
project(':Module1').projectDir=new File('../Module1/module_directory')
```

### X_REPO\Project\app\build.gradle

```
 compile project(':Module1')
```

> Since Android Studio uses same gradle build system, same can be achieved in Android Project as well.